# Last Change Date of linked PDF file to Display on HTML Page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a HTML page which consists of links to PDF files. (Internal company Intranet)
I would like to be able to display on the HTML page next to the links the Last Modified Date to save people having to open the file only to find last months reports. I plan on having only the latest version and obviously would like to be able to tell them when it was last modified .

I know this means I need to do something on the Server side before loading the page to the client.
We are using IIS as software so the obvious answer is ASP.Net (I think) but I do not understand this side of things.
My preferred method would be javascript, if possible,as I have a little experience in that area.

Anyone have any comments or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try use following:

```
// fileInput is a HTMLInputElement: <input type="file" multiple id="myfileinput">
var fileInput = document.getElementById("myfileinput");

// files is a FileList object (simliar to NodeList)
var files = fileInput.files;

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  alert(files[i].name + " has a last modified date of " + files[i].lastModifiedDate);
}
```